# Using encode to make numbers with string labels in the order I want

Tags: stata

I've read how to do this and I thought I knew, based on this article:
http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/ordering-results-of-tabulation/

`DEBTPhaseString` is a string variable with six values: Start, Readiness, On The Path, Nearing The Finish, Out of Poverty, and Completed, in that order.

I'm trying to encode this so the variable will `tabulate` in order, but the variable still tabulates in alphabetical order. Here's my code.

```
label define PhaseOrder 1 "Start" 2 "Readiness" 3 "On The Path" 4 "Nearing The Finish" 5 "Out of Poverty" 6 "Completed"

gen DEBTPhaseString = "On The Path"
replace DEBTPhaseString = "Nearing The Finish" if DEBTNegativeMR<=OTPDebtGoal
replace DEBTPhaseString = "Out of Poverty" if DEBTNegativeMR<=NTFDebtGoal
replace DEBTPhaseString = "Completed" if DEBTNegativeMR==0
replace DEBTPhaseString = "" if DEBTNegativeMR==.
encode DEBTPhaseString, gen(DEBTPhase) label(PhaseOrder)
tab DEBTPhase
```

[tab result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsErd.png)

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that your strategy is utterly correct. The bad news is that your problem is not reproducible. We don't have your dataset and can't see all your code that may be relevant. See also in general https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

This example is self-contained and proof of principle.

There will be some little typo somewhere -- confusion between variable names or some such -- but we, more precisely I, can't say what it is. Check carefully e.g. the results of `describe DEBT*`.

```
clear 
set obs 6 

gen DEBTPhaseString = "On The Path" in 1 
replace DEBTPhaseString = "Nearing The Finish" in 2
replace DEBTPhaseString = "Out of Poverty" in 3 
replace DEBTPhaseString = "Completed" in 4 
replace DEBTPhaseString = "Start" in 5 
replace DEBTPhaseString = "Readiness" in 6  

label define PhaseOrder 1 "Start" 2 "Readiness" 3 "On The Path" 4 "Nearing The Finish" 5 "Out of Poverty" 6 "Completed"
encode DEBTPhaseString, gen(DEBTPhase) label(PhaseOrder)

tab DEBTPhase

         DEBTPhase |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
-------------------+-----------------------------------
             Start |          1       16.67       16.67
         Readiness |          1       16.67       33.33
       On The Path |          1       16.67       50.00
Nearing The Finish |          1       16.67       66.67
    Out of Poverty |          1       16.67       83.33
         Completed |          1       16.67      100.00
-------------------+-----------------------------------
             Total |          6      100.00
```